# Compass Search Annotations cause compiler errors

Tags: annotations, full-text-search, compass-lucene

I'm trying to use the @Searchable annotations from the Compass search engine in my Java program, but I receive a compile-time error: "type mismatch: cannot convert Searchable to Annotation".

I have included all of the jar files that I can think of, and scoured the web for working examples to no avail.

Does anyone have a working example of Compass annotations?

Answer (score 2):

> "type mismatch: cannot convert Searchable to Annotation"

This error is caused by the Searchable class coming from **compass14-x.x.x.jar**. In your Compass library put **compass14-x.x.x.jar** down to the bottom or remove it if you don't need it. The right Searchable class is in **compass-x.x.x.jar**.